# Serve translations using react-intl

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

The project I'm currently working uses `react-intl` to handle the i18n and I noticed that components are fed with the formatted message in 3 different ways:

1. Using a component: `<FormattedMessage id="MessageId" />`
2. Using a function: `intl.formatMessage({id: "MessageId"})`
3. Directly using the messages object: `intl.messages["MessageId"]`

I think approach #1 and #2 are the way to go but I think #3 is very limiting.

What are some good reasons to use #3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is the react way and is recommended if you are using ReactJS. The `FormattedMessage` component [uses `useIntl`](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/blob/8c4f4362166076a296ed1701941d910172fe84ac/packages/react-intl/src/components/message.tsx#L33) hook to access the `intl` object internally (approach #2):

```
<FormattedMessage id="GREETING" />
```

The second approach uses the `intl` object directly without the React abstraction. Use this if you are integrating the intl API with other unsupported frameworks.

```
intl.formatMessage({ id: "GREETING" })
```

Don't ever use the third approach. `intl.messages` is just a normal Javascript object that maps each `MessageId` to the translated text. You can't even use the [ICU Message Formatting](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/messages/). For example:

```json
{
  "GREETING": "Hello, {name}"
}
```

```
intl.formatMessage({ id: "GREETING" }, { name: "Near" }); // Hello, Near
intl.messages["GREETING"]; // Hello, {name}
```